# Protection current

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, resistors, diodes

How to find the maximum injection current that the internal (clamping) diode can withstand?

It is not mentioned in this [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-6500-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3S4-SAM3S2-SAM3S1_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: It is not mentioned in the datasheet as it is not a guaranteed parameter. Obey the published specs or ask your friends at Microchip.

Comment: I might ask why you need this information? The clamping diodes are not supposed to be conducting current in any case under any normal condition, as you must obey the voltage limits of IO pins, and if you do, then there will be no clamping current.

Comment: @Justme, suppose, there is some untoward incident, in that case, I would want to ensure that how much would be the maximum current that the internal diode can handle?

Comment: Assuming that you want to calculate a protective series resistor on pins used as inputs (please add that important information by [edit]ing your question), put it the other way around. Use the maximum leakage current to find the maximum resistor value to provided accepted logic voltages, and use a bit less.